# Reference for inequality for TV of positive measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu,\nu$ be positive measures on some measurable space $(X,\mathcal{F})$. 
Let $||\mu-\nu||$ denote the total variation distance between $\mu$ and $\nu$.
Is the inequality
$$ ||\mu-\nu|| \le 2(|\mu(X)-\nu(X)| + \min\{\mu(X),\nu(X)\})$$
known? Can someone provide a reference? (Not asking for a proof.)

Edit: An equivalent form, of course, is
$$ ||\mu-\nu|| \le \mu(X)+\nu(X)+|\mu(X)-\nu(X)|=2\max\{\mu(X),\nu(X)\}).$$

Comment: This inequality is weaker than the usual triangle inequality $\|\mu - \nu\| \leqslant \|\mu\| + \|\nu\| = \mu(X) + \nu(X)$.

Comment: Yes, of course -- I see that now, with the equivalent form!